# Android N Display size optout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-7.0-nougat

Android N display size setting changes the APP UI. Is there anyway to set fixed size of the UI even if the user changes the display size in android N device. In my app running webview as UI.

Answer (score -1):

Android N display Size through compute the screen width and height,to scale screen mode ,there is no way to fixed size of the Ui,but i think u could use custom view to do that,just scale the view like display image more and more big.